# Rails, multiple css outputs in build:css script prevents --watch from working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

With Rails 7, if I have multiple outputs for my `build:css` script in `package.json`, --watch` no longer works, how can I output multiple files and still enable the script to rebuild the css when file changes are made?

Example, this does *not* work:

```
"build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass.scss ./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules && sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.sass.scss ./app/assets/builds/active_admin.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules"
```

While if I remove the `&&` and everything that follows like so:

```
"build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass.scss ./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules"
```

That *does* work, and the files are observed for changes and rebuilt, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `--watch` flag is just appended to `build:css` command and it ends up executing this

```
sass ... && sass ... --watch
```

It compiles `application.scss` and then watches `admin.scss`.

This is the correct syntax:

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/dart-sass#many-to-many-mode

```
sass [<input.css>:<output.css>] [<input/>:<output/>]...
```

```
"build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass.scss:./app/assets/builds/application.css ./app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.sass.scss:./app/assets/builds/active_admin.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules"
```